# log4jdbc Java 8 compatibility

Tags: java, java-8, wso2, log4jdbc

I'm trying to monitor my MySQL database queries using log4jdbc. I have a WSO2 Identity server running with Java 8. I followed the instructions in [1] and getting the following error.

```
[2019-01-11 15:19:37,590] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm} -  nullType class java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: nullType class java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.createObjectWithOptions(DefaultRealm.java:395)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.initializeObjects(DefaultRealm.java:222)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.init(DefaultRealm.java:127)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.initializeRealm(DefaultRealmService.java:264)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.<init>(DefaultRealmService.java:102)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.<init>(DefaultRealmService.java:115)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.Activator.startDeploy(Activator.java:72)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.BundleCheckActivator.start(BundleCheckActivator.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:711)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:702)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.resume(AbstractBundle.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.resumeBundle(Framework.java:1176)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:559)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:544)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.incFWSL(StartLevelManager.java:457)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.doSetStartLevel(StartLevelManager.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:438)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.createObjectWithOptions(DefaultRealm.java:349)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: Error occurred while checking is existing domain : PRIMARY for tenant : -1234
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.util.UserCoreUtil.persistDomain(UserCoreUtil.java:837)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager.persistDomain(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:6028)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.jdbc.JDBCUserStoreManager.<init>(JDBCUserStoreManager.java:297)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.jdbc.JDBCUserStoreManager.<init>(JDBCUserStoreManager.java:239)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: DB error occurred while checking is existing domain : PRIMARY & tenant id : -1234
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.util.UserCoreUtil.isExistingDomain(UserCoreUtil.java:989)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.util.UserCoreUtil.persistDomain(UserCoreUtil.java:825)
    ... 30 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: net.sf.log4jdbc.sql.jdbcapi.DriverSpy cannot be found by jdbc-pool_7.0.81.wso2v2
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:254)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:182)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:730)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:664)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.getConnection(ConnectionPool.java:200)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.getConnection(DataSourceProxy.java:127)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.util.DatabaseUtil.getDBConnection(DatabaseUtil.java:868)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.util.UserCoreUtil.isExistingDomain(UserCoreUtil.java:971)
    ... 31 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.sf.log4jdbc.sql.jdbcapi.DriverSpy cannot be found by jdbc-pool_7.0.81.wso2v2
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:501)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:421)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:412)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:246)
    ... 38 more
[2019-01-11 15:19:37,603] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.Activator} -  Cannot start User Manager Core bundle
org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: Cannot initialize the realm.
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.initializeRealm(DefaultRealmService.java:274)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.<init>(DefaultRealmService.java:102)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.<init>(DefaultRealmService.java:115)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.Activator.startDeploy(Activator.java:72)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.BundleCheckActivator.start(BundleCheckActivator.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:711)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:702)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.resume(AbstractBundle.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.resumeBundle(Framework.java:1176)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:559)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:544)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.incFWSL(StartLevelManager.java:457)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.doSetStartLevel(StartLevelManager.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:438)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: nullType class java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.initializeObjects(DefaultRealm.java:316)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.init(DefaultRealm.java:127)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.initializeRealm(DefaultRealmService.java:264)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: nullType class java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.createObjectWithOptions(DefaultRealm.java:395)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.initializeObjects(DefaultRealm.java:222)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.createObjectWithOptions(DefaultRealm.java:349)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: Error occurred while checking is existing domain : PRIMARY for tenant : -1234
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.util.UserCoreUtil.persistDomain(UserCoreUtil.java:837)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager.persistDomain(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:6028)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.jdbc.JDBCUserStoreManager.<init>(JDBCUserStoreManager.java:297)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.jdbc.JDBCUserStoreManager.<init>(JDBCUserStoreManager.java:239)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: DB error occurred while checking is existing domain : PRIMARY & tenant id : -1234
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.util.UserCoreUtil.isExistingDomain(UserCoreUtil.java:989)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.util.UserCoreUtil.persistDomain(UserCoreUtil.java:825)
    ... 30 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: net.sf.log4jdbc.sql.jdbcapi.DriverSpy cannot be found by jdbc-pool_7.0.81.wso2v2
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:254)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:182)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:730)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:664)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.getConnection(ConnectionPool.java:200)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.getConnection(DataSourceProxy.java:127)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.util.DatabaseUtil.getDBConnection(DatabaseUtil.java:868)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.util.UserCoreUtil.isExistingDomain(UserCoreUtil.java:971)
    ... 31 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.sf.log4jdbc.sql.jdbcapi.DriverSpy cannot be found by jdbc-pool_7.0.81.wso2v2
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:501)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:421)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:412)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:246)
    ... 38 more
```

My log4jdbc version is log4jdbc4-1.2.jar. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

1. http://msmshariq.blogspot.com/2015/03/troubleshooting-wso2-server-database.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a class not found error. Can you try with this class name?

```
<driverClassName>net.sf.log4jdbc.DriverSpy</driverClassName>
```

Ref: http://movingaheadblog.blogspot.com/2016/07/how-to-use-log4jdbc-with-wso2-products_28.html